# Have 200+ Pakistani military personnel been killed in the past 6 months by "insurgents crossing the border"?

Tags: war, india, pakistan, afghanistan

In an Aug 12 story, AP reported the claims of some Pakistani officials [that](https://apnews.com/article/religion-pakistan-taliban-b6308923395cd6942b698a748728d11d#:%7E:text=In%20the%20last%20six%20months%2C%20they%20say%20more%20than%20200%20Pakistani%20military%20personnel%20have%20been%20killed%20by%20insurgents%20crossing%20the%20border%2C)

> Pakistan has its own concerns, accusing Afghanistan of harboring militants opposed to the Islamabad government. Pakistani security officials say their country’s rival India is allowed by Kabul’s intelligence agency to stage covert attacks against Pakistan using militants in Afghanistan. In the last six months, they say **more than 200 Pakistani military personnel have been killed by insurgents crossing the border**[.]

Is there any independent verification of the alleged scale of Pakistani military personnel losses due to "insurgents crossing the border"?

Comment: So the claim is that India sends troops to Afghanistan so that they can then cross the Afghan-Pakistani border to assault Pakistani troops? Despite there being [no border between India and Afghanistan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcpxI.gif)? Is that correct? If true it would mean India flies troops to Afghanistan for this purpose?

Comment: @fredsbend: the claim as to how India exactly does this is rather vague; it's only referring to "using militants in Afghanistan". I'm guessing Pakistan is blaming attacks by [TTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tehrik-i-Taliban_Pakistan) and [BLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balochistan_Liberation_Army), and even "accidental" skirmishes with Afghan Taliban crossing the border ultimately as being "supported" by India, but since that can be much harder to prove or disprove, I'm just asking about the scale of the attacks.